# How to handle swollen MacBook battery after several weeks of storage?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

Several weeks ago, I noticed a swollen lithium-ion battery in an older MacBook laptop. Substantial swelling, the battery looks almost twice as thick as normal near one corner. I initially noticed the swelling because it deformed the bottom plate of the laptop. Since then, I have not used the device and currently am storing it in a fire safe location. Unfortunately, the battery is screwed in place inside the laptop and I initially worried that unscrewing might cause further damage or put pressure on the battery. Now, that it has been a while since I noticed the damage to the battery, I assume that it has discharged substantially (though the state of charge was unknown at the time of failure).

Is this assumption safe to make? Can I expect that the danger of fire is lower after safely storing it for this period of time and not observing any changes? Do you think that there is still danger in unscrewing and removing the battery? How cautiously should I need to handle the battery?

Comment: Discharging the battery by operating the Macbook is probably a good idea.| Once it is as discharged as you can reasonably make it,  - As JimmyB says , removing it with sensible care is probably the best idea.

Comment: I did not consider manually discharging the battery because I expected it to be more dangerous than just letting it sit without a current. So would you consider powering it on to see if there is still enough voltage from the cells to power the computer? Or is there another (safer) way to slowly discharge?

Comment: @user73014  How much swelling?  A amount of moderate swelling is acceptable for a lithium battery.  A photo might help here.

Comment: @user73014 Discharge by turning the computer on probably will not cause problems (nothing in life is certain). IF you have access to the terminals you could use a suitably low-current load BUT I personally would be happy to carefully and sensibly dismantle the system and remove the battery. It is more likely than not that the battery swelling is not a very major hazard, but it is best to eliminate the possibility than to risk the PC's (and your) safety.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Not sure if having *any* current flow through the battery is actually a good idea. Sounds like more risky than just removing the battery to me.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Substantial swelling, the battery looks almost twice as thick as normal near one corner. I initially noticed the swelling because it deformed the bottom plate of the laptop

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Are there any other factors I could check for that might influence your advice contradictory to JimmyB’s? I have not had a chance to remove the battery yet and am thinking about whether to discharge or not

Comment: @user73014 GET THE BATTERY OUT OF THE LAPTOP ONE WAY OR THE OTHER. If you are confident that you can remove it without shorting the battery then I agree that that is the best way. I would not expect much added hazard in discharging the battery by operating the laptop - but "just removing it" is better **IF** you can do it without shorting it. Note that this SHOULD be a rather easy task - BUT I am not acquainted with the laptop you are using. If there is a plug in connector that you can unplug without hazard then that's probably an OK choice. BUT GET THE BATTERY OUT ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I expect that the danger of fire is lower after safely storing it
>   for this period of time and not observing any changes?

No. It may already be deeply discharged, or it may be 50% full. No way to tell from "the state of charge was unknown" and "it has been a while".

> Do you think that there is still danger in unscrewing and removing the
>   battery?

No. A battery is not nitroglycerin. Moving it without bending or pressing on it is safe. I'd say that it probably can be removed from the device without significant mechanical stress, so the 'risk' depends on how careful you are. You already know that you don't want to apply force to the battery in the process, but I believe you won't have to.

I feel that the risk of letting it sit where it is is much higher than removing and securing it a.s.a.p. If it starts to burn right now, at least the MacBook will burn too, so **get rid of the battery as soon as you can.**

Comment: Just want to make sure Russell McMahon's comment stays near this answer: run the battery down as low as possible before removing. Furthermore, make sure you **do not** short the battery terminals...doing so would make removing the battery much more dangerous than leaving it in place.

Comment: A swollen battery means at least one cell has 'out-gassed', But the other cells in the battery will still hold their charge. An out gassed cell is not all that dangerous, it has already passed its failure state without 'venting with flame'. It *should* be entirely safe to run it down in the laptop before removing.

Comment: @jIMMYb We are not in disagreement. I'd have expected he'd have looked at our mutual device and taken one or other course (predischarge using laptop then remove, or just remove.) I've encouraged him to GET IT OUT. You may wish to do so too.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Did it now by bold-ing the last phrase of my answer :)